# Define pen width of a Line layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, polyline-creation

I have created a line shapefile layer (memory layer) created in Python Console of QGIS. Now I want to define the thickness of the line features that are being created. I am aware of the method by which the line styles/symbology can be imported from the existing '.qml' file.

```
self.setLayerSymbology(vlayer, "Parent_PermanentMarks.qml")
```

Is there any way by which symbology (line thickness) of the lines can be defined 'on the go' via python console?

Comment: For shure it is. Did you read the developer cookbook before asking this question? http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers

Comment: @JochenSchwarze ya thank you. Got that.. "symbol.setWidth(0.46)"

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below script worked for me.

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\SampleData\world_borders_lines.shp", "world_borders", "ogr")
props = { 'width' : '2', 'color' : '0,0,255' }
sl = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl])
vlayer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Only change I had to make is to set the path to shapefile like "D:\\abs\\path\\Lines.shp"

Answer (score 4):

Pen width (only line width, not other parameters such as line color) can be set using

```
symbol.setWidth()
```

Full code (Set Line width for the line shapefile layer being loaded):

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:\\abs\\path\\Lines.shp", "LineLayer", "ogr")        
symbols = vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setWidth(0.46)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

NB: To change line color along with pen width, check out the other answer to this question.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why the code you posted answers your question.